# Преобразование массива объектов, полей и их значений JS

Tags: javascript

Я получаю массив объектов такого вида:

```
clientManagers = [
  {
    id: '...',
    disabled: true,
    person: {fullName: 'Иванов Кирилл'}
  },
  {
    id: '...',
    disabled: false,
    person: {fullName: 'Новиков Александр'}
  },
]
```

Моя задача преобразовать данный массив таким образом, чтобы проводилась проверка, если disabled === true, то в person.fullName добавлять к значению '(Неактив.)'. В итоге должен возвращаться вот такой массив объектов:

```
clientManagers = [
  {
    id: '...',
    disabled: true,
    person: {fullName: 'Иванов Кирилл (Неактив.)'}
  },
  {
    id: '...',
    disabled: false,
    person: {fullName: 'Новиков Александр'}
  },
]
```

Пробовал преобразовывать массив с помощью метода map, но каждый раз получаю разного рода ошибки, если есть варианты, как лучше преобразовать массив таким образом, буду благодарен.

```
const clientManagersDisabled = clientManagers.map((manager, index) => {
    return clientManagers[index].disabled === true
      ? `${clientManagers[index].person.fullName}(Неактив.)`
      : clientManagers[index].person.fullName;
  });
```

Вот пример моего кода, при том что значения возвращаются правильные, но суть в том, что мне нужно вернуть этот массив в первоначальном виде, но с изменёнными значениями, как я демонстрировал выше, данный код возвращает

```
['Иванов Кирилл(Неактив.)', 'Новиков Александр']
```

Comment: "получаю разного рода ошибки," --- какие например? приведите код

Comment: а вообще нет смысла модифицировать массив. правильнее будет при выводе данных в html добавлять  статус активности.

Comment: `map` тут логически тоже не особо корректен. таки предназначен для преобразования структуры

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я бы и рад сделать что-то проще, но массив приходит ко мне в таком виде и задача поставлена именно в таком ключе, что опираясь на поле disabled, я должен интегрировать значение '(Неактив.)' к полю fullName, так как далее идёт огромный кусок логики работы непосредственно с этим массивом, который уже не относится к задаче

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clientManagers.map((client) => ({
    ...client,
    person: {
        ...client.person, //Если у person будут другие поля
        fullName: client.disabled ? client.person.fullName + ' (Неактив.)' : client.person.fullName
    }
}))
```

А вообще и вправду тут не особо корректно преобразовывать массив, проще сразу в шаблоне менять вывод.

Comment: вам не кажется что `function(c){ if(c.disabled) { c.person.fullanme += "(....)";} return c; }}`  в разы читаемей, чем вот то что у вас написано?

Answer (score 0):

Просто пройдитесь по массиву и измените именование

```
clientManagers.forEach(function(c){
   if(c.disabled) c.person.fullName += "(inactive)";

   // или, хотя и менее читаемо
   // c.person.fullName += (c.disabled ? "(inactive)" : "") ;
});
```

но в целом, это не имеет особого смысла. надо просто учитывать при выводе, а не модифицировать данные.